# regex to parse first and last name

Tags: regex

I parse some logs and in some case user name shown as FirstName.LastName in the other cases it shown as FLastName. I am just wonder if it is possible to parse both to names to FLastName. 
For example Joe.Doe and JDoe should both yeild JDoe.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
(.)(?:[^\.]*\.)(.+)$
```

Basically it grabs the first character and then allows for multiple characters followed by a dot and then grabs the rest. The replacement string would be:

```
$1$2
```

But that depends on your regex tool that you're using.

[Try it on RegExr](http://regexr.com?2ton2) (thanks stema, I didn't know about this site).

Comment: It can not match JDoe because the `.` is not optional.

Comment: That is not true, the last part `(.+)` will catch the JDoe case.

Comment: Your regex does not match JDoe, but because it does not match, nothing will be replaced, everything is fine. @anubhava opened my eyes (thanks ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what regex platform you are using but this will work in sed:

```
sed 's/\([a-z[A-Z]\).*\.\(.*\)$/\1\2/'
```

For strings `"FirstName.LastName` and `FLastName` it gives output:

```
FLastName
```

Comment: It can not match JDoe because the `.` is not optional.

Comment: Correct and that is by purpose, If you run above `JDoe` will remain `JDoe` and that is what you want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, (but the other two will work as well)

```
^([a-zA-Z])(?:.*\.)?(.*)$
```

[See online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tomv)

It matches the first letter, then the following part till the dot is optional. At last matches the string till the end. The first letter is in group 1 and the LastName is in group 2.

So replace with $1$2 (or \1\2, depending on your regex engine)